# Проблема с SessionExpired steam

Tags: node.js, steam

Всем доброго времени суток!
Прошу помощи у знающих людей, суть проблемы заключается в том что, у меня есть бот для одной торговой площадки стим, но бывает что сессия закрывается и он не может переподключиться. То есть, при обрыве сессии, вызывается `community.on( 'sessionExpired', function( error ) {...} );` в нем я вызываю `client.connect();` и после этого я получаю ошибку `Error: Disconnected` в `client.on( 'error', function( err ) {...} );` и при этой ошибке у меня опять же идет попытка подключения и получается что стим, временно блокирует авторизацию боту из за многократных, не верных попыток входа. Прошу вашей помощи!

```
const Crypto = require( 'crypto' );
    const Steam = require( 'steam' );
    const SteamTotp = require( 'steam-totp' );
    const SteamWebLogon = require( 'steam-weblogon' );
    const SteamCommunity = require( 'steamcommunity' );
    const TradeOfferManager = require( 'steam-tradeoffer-manager' );

    const client = new Steam.SteamClient();
    const user = new Steam.SteamUser( client );
    const webLogon = new SteamWebLogon( client, user );
    const community = new SteamCommunity();
    const manager = new TradeOfferManager( { 
        steam: client,
        community: community,
        language: 'en',
        cancelTime: 150000
    } );

    const loginOpt = { 
        account_name: config.steam.accountName,
        password: config.steam.password,
        two_factor_code: SteamTotp.generateAuthCode( config.steam.shared_secret )
    };

    //var reconnect = false;
    var reconnectTimer;

    client.connect();

    client.on( 'connected', function() { 
        //console.log( 'connected' );
        user.logOn( loginOpt );
    } );

    client.on( 'error', function( err ) { 
        //if( reconnect ) {
            if( err.toString().indexOf( 'Error: Disconnected' ) > -1 ) {
                //reconnect = false;
                loggerMess( 'Потеря соединения со Steam. Переподключение... (60сек)', 'info' );
                reconnectTimer = setTimeout( function() { 
                    client.connect(); 
                }, 60000 );
                //console.log( 'Error: Disconnected' );     
            } else loggerMess( err, 'error' );
        //}
    } );

    client.on( 'logOnResponse', function( res ) {
        //console.log( 'logOnResponse: ' + res );
        if( res.eresult === Steam.EResult.OK ) {
            loggerMess( 'Авторизация Steam прошла успешно!', 'good' );
            webLogon.webLogOn( function( sessionID, cookies ) { 
                manager.setCookies( cookies );
                community.setCookies( cookies );
                community.startConfirmationChecker( config.steam.refreshInterval, config.steam.identity_secret );
            } );

            //reconnect = true;
            if( reconnectTimer ) clearTimeout( reconnectTimer );
        }
    } );

    community.on( 'sessionExpired', function( error ) {
        //if( error ) loggerMess( error, 'error' );
        //if( reconnect ) {
            //reconnect = false;
            loggerMess( 'Завершение сессии. Переподключение... (60сек)', 'info' );
            reconnectTimer = setTimeout( function() {
                client.connect(); 
            }, 60000 );
            //console.log( 'sessionExpired' );
        //}
    });

    user.on( 'updateMachineAuth', function( sentry, callback ) { 
        fs.writeFile( 'sentry', sentry.bytes );
        callback( { sha_file: getSHA1( sentry.bytes ) } );
    } );

    manager.on( 'newOffer', function( offer ) {
        ...
    } );

    function getSHA1( bytes ) {
        var shasum = Crypto.createHash( 'sha1' );
        shasum.end( bytes );
        return shasum.read();
    }
```

Comment: Если начинает валится ошибка при переподключении, вы пробовали все выключить и заново запустить программу? После этого логинится нормально?

Comment: У меня было именно так. Я удалял все объекты `client`, `user` и тд, создавал их заново и делал `client.connect();`

Comment: Костыль, но если надо решить быстро, то можно использовать